# No output sound with my Xonar D1 in 16.04 (16.10 works)

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 16.10

I have a Xonar D1 installed and I can see it in `aplay -l`, in `pavucontrol`, in `sound` and all other applications.

I can select its *microphone in*, its *analogue stereo output* and other options. When I play mp3, music and other audio source, I can see in the different sound utilities that the sound itself is being sent to the card.
According to what I observed, it should work just fine.

But it does not.

On Ubuntu 16.04 I can only use the *microphone in*, but the out doesn't work. I simply hear **nothing**. Instead, on Ubuntu 16.10, fresh from bootable USB stick, it **works as intended**.

I have tried many different solutions:

- `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`. Didn't help.
- `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`, followed by `sudo rm /var/lib/alsa/asound.state` and then by `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`. Didn't help.

This is my `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: D1 [Xonar D1], device 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: D1 [Xonar D1], device 1: Digital [Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC898 Analog [ALC898 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC898 Digital [ALC898 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`pulseaudio` I'm using is version 8.0, packages repositories I use are:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                            
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                            
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stefansundin/truecrypt/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                             
Ign:7 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease                                                  
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                   
Hit:9 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release                              
Get:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
```

What should I do next? Any idea?
How should I reset all the configuration files related to sound? I'm *really* speechless at this point...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you switch the output with `alsamixer -c0`?

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: @CL. this doesn't make any difference I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this link on archlinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=841709#p841709)

> Under alsamixer, I just had to MUTE S/PDIF for the sound to play back
>   again. Please wait for me while I smash my head against the wall.

I then decided to mute the *front panel* on `alsamixer`. Of course now it works. Just fine. I'm genuinely speechless!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone starting with this problem and can see the Xonar D1 in `sound`, first try all the surround options for the Analog Output in `sound`.